# Tomcat 8 Could not load keystore file

Tags: java, tomcat, redhat, keystore

I have Tocmat 8 installed on redhat 7
Everything works fine, the problem when I run my project, I just got this error:

> Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Could not load keystore
>   file.

**conf/server.xml**

```
<Connector port="443"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
        maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https"
        secure="true"
        keystoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat8.5/8.5.23/conf/.keystore"
        keystorePass="*****"
        clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I tried this command:

> keytool -list -v -keystore ../conf/.keystore

and everything is OK, the problem is just when I run my application, I found in the log file localhost.2017-10-11.log a keystore exception.

Any help !

Comment: 1. when you try with keytool, use exactly the same path from config file, just to rule out any error in the path. 2. what account are you running tomcat under? Does it have sufficient access to the keystore file?

Comment: Yes i have cheked the permission for the user tomcat, and the path also

Comment: Have you tried to pass the keystore type ? For example if your keystore type is PKCS12, try to put `keystoreType="PKCS12"` in your connector.

Comment: What is that caused-by caused by?

Comment: try running with this command param (or set it using `System.setProperty()`):   `javax.net.debug=ssl` In the debug otput at the top it should show which keystore it is trying to load.